# How to use Named Array Constant to fill an Active-X ComboBox in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, named

I'd like to setup my ComboBox values as a named array constant, where you go into the Name Manager and define a name and give it a value like:

```
={"A", "B", "C"}
```

I've found that ListFillRange will only take a Range so I can't assign to that.

Though it would work for a normal named range, like so:

```
myComboBox.ListFillRange = "MyList"
```

So how do you assign a Named Array Constant to fill a ComboBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much searching I found this solution:

```
myComboBox.List() = Evaluate(ThisWorkbook.Names("MyList").RefersTo)
```

Comment: You can also use "Value" instead of "RefersTo".

Answer (score 1):

I can't get your method to work for me but it's probably my setup?

If it were me attempting this I would either

1. Load the list programmatically item by item

or

2i) Assume arbitrarily "J" is the listfill range

2ii) Define a named range, say  "COLJ"  = =Sheet1!$J$2:INDEX($J$2:$J$65000,COUNTA($J$2:$J$65000))

2ii) Copy/Filter the items you want into J2:Jx

2ii) Assign the Listfillrange using VBA,  myComboBox.ListFillRange = "COLJ"

Comment: I was intentionally trying to avoid having my lists in cells or in VBA.  I don't like the kluge of having my combobox lists in cells. It would have been ok for my current project to assign things in VBA, but I was looking for a solution that would be consistent and capable for all of my spreadsheets.

Comment: I agree with you but Excel/VBA/Userforms create the kluge :) What I do know is that 'Advanced Filter' is your friend in Excel. Also if your lists are NOT in the same worksheet as the control then problems arise.